# Git - How to merge a remote branch into remote master

Tags: git, github

So here's the situation.

I created a local branch.  Then I pushed that local branch to github.  So github now has two branches.

Now I want to merge the two branches together both locally and on github.

This is probably a dumb question but somehow I'm not seeing it in the documentation.

So far my best guess is to merge locally, and then delete the remote branch from github?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You create a merge of your feature branch locally, push the branch you merged to (probably "master") to github. Github will now contain the merge. Then delete your local and remote copy of the feature branch.

Answer (score 3):

Just merge the branch locally into the master branch and push that to github's master branch.