# How can I merge remote branches without going to github?

Tags: git, github, merge

I have pushed my local branch "develop" into the remote branch "develop".

Now, I want to merge contents of remote "develop" into remote "master" without going to github website.

I tried to checkout to the remote master by typing `git checkout origin/master`, but displays "You are in 'detached HEAD' state."

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Isn't this exactly what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651185/git-merge-a-remote-branch-locally

Answer (score 3):

You can find the answer here.. [Git - How to merge a remote branch into remote master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972399/git-how-to-merge-a-remote-branch-into-remote-master).

There is no way you can merge remote branches directly from your local git repo. You have to merge the branch into local master branch and then push the changes to remote master.

Answer (score 1):

You could update both branches on your local, merge them, and push to master
You might want  do the following

`git checkout develop`

`git pull origin develop`

`git checkout master`

`git pull origin master`

`git merge develop`

If you have no conflicts, and everything is fine then, update the contents of origin/master with the new changes

`git push origin master`

This way you can easily merge the contents of origin/develop to origin/master without going to github.

Comment: this is a nice step by step explanation but it doesn't address the question.